# android canvas uses screen origin instead of view origin after translation

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using a custom view and canvas to draw objects on screen. The view is at a Y offset from the screen origin. I want to translate the canvas and then draw an object. However, when I do a translate the canvas using setmatrix, the origin shifts from view origin to screen origin. As per the below code, the circle should be drawn at the view origin. But I need to add the offset of the view from the screen origin while drawing the circle. How do I achieve the desired result?

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{           
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPaint(canvasPaint);
    m_canvasMatrix.set(getMatrix());
    m_canvasMatrix.postTranslate(-100, -100);
    canvas.setMatrix(m_canvasMatrix);
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 20, circlePaint);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but I *think* what you're trying to do is to simply apply a relative translation to the `Canvas`. In which case, you're almost thinking about things too hard. All you need to do is:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{ 
    canvas.save();


    canvas.translate(100, 0);


    // At this point, drawing something (such as a square) with a top-left
    // corner at 0,0 would result in a square that's drawn with its top-left
    // 100px to the right of the left bound of the View.


    ...

    canvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Trevor for your quick reply. I will be doing lot of translation, scaling and rotation and hence would like to save the canvas state in a matrix. However, whenever I do canvas.SetMatrix, the canvas takes the screen origin and not my view origin. Any ideas?

Comment: The `save()` and `restore()` methods already allow the canvas' matrix state to be preserved, so that the canvas ends up having exactly the same matrix after your `onDraw()` finishes as it did when it started. Usually you would not care about what the canvas' current matrix actually is on entry to `onDraw()`. Perhaps what you've not realised is that when you perform the various `.translate()` operations and so forth, you're actually pre-concatenating the current matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. I did not use canvas save/restore but I stopped using matrices. I had to change the whole logic. Thanks a lot. Your guidance helped me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that one (including me, initially ;-) intuitively excpects the initial matrix of the canvas to be the identity matrix. In fact it is not. It instead contains the neccesary transform from screen to client coordinates. If you simply set the matrix of the canvas you effectively erase this transformation, which is why your circle's origin is at screen-(0,0).

To circumvent this, simply concat your matrix to the existing one of the canvas:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{           
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPaint(canvasPaint);
    m_canvasMatrix.set(getMatrix());
    m_canvasMatrix.postTranslate(-100, -100);
    canvas.concat(m_canvasMatrix); // <- !!!
    canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 20, circlePaint);
}
```

One remark for the C# folks out there:

```
canvas.Matrix.PreConcat(myMatrix) // <- !!! WRONG !!!
```

won't work! (think about it: the setter of Matrix won't be invoked...)

Instead use:

```
Matrix tmpMatrix = canvas.Matrix;
tmpMatrix.PreConcat(myMatrix);
canvas.Matrix = tmpMatrix;
```

or simply:

```
canvas.Concat(myMatrix);
```